# PowerShell - Rename Files based on a matching .basename

Tags: windows, powershell, rename, microsoft-file-explorer

I am looking to rename a .wav file when the corresponding .txt file is renamed

The Files have the same basename but are different file types.

I am using get-content on the .txt file to get the name I would like to use.

But cant seems to get the .wav files linked with the matching .txt files.

Any help would be much appreciated on this

this code is what I am using to update the .txt files at once individually using their data.
Not sure how I can add the .wav feature within this.

```
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem c:\test\*.txt
>> foreach ($File in $txtFiles) {
>>     $File.fullname
>>     $Data = (get-content $File.fullname)[6,7,4]-Join 1
>> $Data = $Data -Replace ":",","
>>     $Rename = (Rename-item $file -NewName $file$data)
>>
>> }
```

I was thinking maybe something like this would be on the nose of what I need, but not 100% sure

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\test" -recurse | where {$_.fullname.wav -like $_.fullname.txt} | Select name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group your `*.txt` and `*.wav` files by shared base name (file name without extension):

```bash
Get-ChildItem c:\test\*.txt, c:\test\*.wave | 
  Group-Object BaseName |
  ForEach-Object {
    $pairedFiles = $_.Group
    $data = (Get-Content $pairedFiles[0].FullName)[6,7,4] -join 1 -replace ':', ','
    $pairedFiles |
      Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + $data + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>